# Winforms DataSet in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, dataset

I'm recreating a Winforms application in WPF, and I'm stuck with `DataSet` (System.Data.DataSet).

In the Components view I can see `DataSet` under Windows Forms Controls, but I cannot use it, it is grayed out.

I'm not experienced in WPF, I've searched over Google, but all that I found was using s SQL Database as Dataset, but it is not what i need.

Comment: It is strongly recommended that you leave behind the archaic practices from winforms and embrace modern technology. Coupled with WPF, you will use Entity Framework which is the recommended data access technology for all new .Net based applications. Entity Framework allows you to create a strongly typed object model representing your database, which is a much more safe and clean way to operate with your data than the "traditional" (read: archaic) untyped, magic-string based glorified dictionary stuff that DataSets provide. It removes the need for most casts and allows and much cleaner codebase.

Answer (score 1):

In WPF applications, refer to the concept of `DataTable` used for binding purpose: for example, using it's `DefaultView`  as `ItemsSource` property for `DataGrid`. Sample code snippet demonstrates `DataSet` coding technique in `WPF/C#` accessing the `SqlCE` database:

```
// reference Libraries, including SqlCE
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlServerCe;
```

Sample code using DataSet and other data objects

```
private SqlCeDataAdapter dataAdapterSqlCe;
private SqlCeConnection connectionSqlCe;
private DataSet dataSet;
private DataTable dataTable;

// Creating connection to SqlCE DB
connectionSqlCe = new SqlCeConnection(ConnectionString);
connectionSqlCe.Open();

// create new DataAdapter based on connection obj and SelectQuery
dataAdapterSqlCe = new SqlCeDataAdapter();
dataAdapterSqlCe.SelectCommand = new SqlCeCommand(SelectQuery, connectionSqlCe);

// create DataSet
dataSet = new DataSet();

// use DataAdapter to Fill Dataset
dataAdapterSqlCe.Fill(dataTable);

#region Binding dataGrid to dataTable
// DataGrid binding
dataGrid.ItemsSource = dataTable.DefaultView;

// or, alternatively
 dataGrid.DataContext = dataTable;
 #endregion

connectionSqlCe.Close();
```

Hope this will help. Best regards,